# JSONB querying - GREATER THAN or LESS THAN operators

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I'm quite new with JSON and querying data from JSON.
I got to the point, where I want to improve the query with additional filtering options- GREATER THAN and LESS THAN. Existing ruleset query is looking like this (if `=` operator is selected)

`{(id = 111 AND (data @> jsonb_build_object('field', '100')))}`

I've already learned, that `@>` operator checks, if data on the left, matches the data on the right. Now, i would like to check, if that data is greater than or less than.

I have tried using operators themselves (`>` and `<`) and I tried adding `GREATER THAN` or `LESS THAN`, for example:

`{(id = 111 AND (GREATER THAN data @> jsonb_build_object('field', '100')))}`

Is it possible with this kind of query, or I need something completely different?
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Check that what exactly is greater than what? A particular value in that data?

Comment: So, this ```{(id = 111 AND (data @> jsonb_build_object('field', '100')))}``` is checking, if ```data``` is in that jsonb object, that is built on the right (aka - ```data is equal to 100```)

If I want to check, if ```data``` is not equal, I add ```NOT``` in front of the ```data``` and it looks like this-
```{(id = 111 AND (NOT data @> jsonb_build_object('field', '100')))}```
```data``` contains same thing as jsonb object - field name and a numeric value, and I want to compare numeric value from jsonb with numeric value from data. @DanGetz

Comment: You probably want: `(data ->> 'field')::int > 100`

Comment: I need to compare value, that is created in ```jsonb_build_object('field', 'value')``` with ```data``` @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Why do you think you "need" that? If you want to find rows where `data.field` is greater than 100, then `(data ->> 'field')::int > 100` is the way to go. Or maybe `data @@ '$.field > 100'`. But using `>` on a `jsonb` value won't do that. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e19911ea03e5741044a3ffdd522c5228

Comment: I “need” that, because info, that is stored in jsonb object, that I create with ```jsonb_build_object``` is dependent on feature, that is chosen. ```data``` stores the specified filter data- for example- value is 200. 
Anyways, somehow i figured this out, answer posted below. 

If someone says, that they “need” that, it means, that they need that ;) Peace✌ @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow, figured this out by myself.

All the time, I was trying to solve this the wrong way.

To make this work, I needed to:

1. Take the value from objects with `->>` operator. This returns value of specified key as a `string`

`(data->>'fieldName')`

`(jsonb_build_object('fieldName','fieldValue')->>'fieldName')`

(ref:https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html *Table
9-44*);

2. Casted the values from `string` to `numeric` type, so now they can be compared (ref:https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html *4.2.9. Type Casts*)

`(data->>'fieldName')::NUMERIC`

`(jsonb_build_object('fieldName','fieldValue')->>'fieldName')::NUMERIC`

The final result looks something like this-
`(data->>'fieldName')::NUMERIC > (jsonb_build_object('fieldName', 'fieldValue')->>'fieldName')::NUMERIC`

Hope this helps someone later on :)

P.S - This SQL is part of C# webapp, and is generated with help of C# code, so when you add values, thay can change between different objects you apply this for, this part of query makes more sense.

Comment: `(jsonb_build_object('fieldName', 'fieldValue')->>'fieldName')::NUMERIC` can be simplified to `'fieldValue'::numeric`

Comment: I know, but in my usecase, it is useful to see, what is the field name, because there can be multiple different fields at once, so I firstly make that object, and then take the value from it. Imho it’s easier to read and understand later, and performance wise (in my certain usecase) it takes only several miliseconds more, and I’m good with it.